# SQL - CASE STATEMENT - Count statement and case function

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I'm trying to write a `case` `when` function within a count statement, but I have a error 4145.

```
select @CountResult = count(*) from ViewDefinition where DefinitionID = @ObjektID and
    (case 
         when IsGepa=0 and Gepa is not null then @CountResult  
         when NotGepa=0 and GepaListeID is not null then @CountResult  
    end  )

select @CountResult
```

Comment: Formatting code and adding a sql tag

Comment: Your case result isn't being compared against a value, which is needed in a boolean-like clause in the where. What are your intents with that case?

Comment: What DBMS is this for? Not all can handle values as Booleans, only some.

Comment: I have a list with some information. when this 4 condition are true, then the count must go run.

Comment: Please compare your case condition if you are using this in where clause..

Comment: Just to get the nomenclature right: `count()` is a function, `case` is an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select @CountResult = SUM
(
    CASE when (IsGepa=0 and Gepa is not null ) OR (NotGepa=0 and GepaListeID is not null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
from ViewDefinition 
where DefinitionID = @ObjektID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE conditions need to go into the WHERE:

```
select @CountResult = count(*) 
from ViewDefinition 
where DefinitionID = @ObjektID and
  ((IsGepa=0 and Gepa is not null) or  
   (NotGepa=0 and GepaListeID is not null)  
  )

select @CountResult
```